# Бац-бац-бац-бац / бац, бац, бац, бац

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно?

> Бац-бац-бац-бац / бац, бац, бац, бац.

> Цыц-цыц! / Цыц, цыц!

> Цып-цып-цып, цып, цып, цып.

> Мяу-мяу-мяу / мяу, мяу, мяу.

Comment: Разные звуки, Котыквин, может быть кап-кап, а может быть отдельно - кап, кап-кап, кап-кап-кап.